# Why is there no new line after paragraph sectioning commands?

Tags: sectioning, typography, sections-paragraphs

I'd love to know why traditional document classes are not including a new line after the `\paragraph` sectioning command. Maybe there is some typographic history behind it or something (maybe not and this is a totally dumb question), just curious. Searching the web wasn't from help to answer this.

Comment: Note that in `amsart`, there's no new line even after `\subsection`, which is two levels higher than `\paragraph`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most latex sectioning commands (below `\chapter`) are handled by the internal `\@startsection` macro. This implements two distinct styles of heading *display* headings that are offset vertically from the following paragraph, and *inline* headings that are set as the initial part of the following paragraph.

The standard classes switch style to inline at the `\paragraph` level although it is easy to redefine them back if you wish.

Inline "headings" are not that uncommon but sometimes "heading" text isn't really a heading but just the first word(s) of the paragraph. The setting is often similar to that of a `description` environment which is often another alternative markup at this level, there isn't really a hard line between sectional units of a document and a list once you get down to level 5 or 6 headings.

Comment: Many thanks, I always wonder why there is that gap between the `\paragraph{}` output and the text that follows. You're absolutely right with the *just the first words* assessment. Never heard of the `description` environment, gotta check this out right now. I'll give other people the chance to answer the question, if nothing better comes up, this will be it. **EDIT:** `description` is equivalent to the `<dl>` tag in HTML, got it. :)

Comment: @Fleshgrinder `\@startsection`'s argument for inline headings specifies the horizontal space after the heading, Leslie was clearly thinking of it more of a heading than just initial words as it is specified as 1em space in article class rather than something closer to a word space, but it's just an example, he probably wasn't expecting to be setting the typographic standards for the next 30 years at the time:-)

Comment: @Fleshgrinder yes `description` is similar to html's dl (although html is of course quite a bit later than latex in design)

Comment: He sure wasn't. :D Sure HTML was much later and I guess they had a look at LaTeX as well during their decision on which tags are necessary for typesetting. The semantics of both are absolutely equal.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what document class you're dealing with, but if you have a preference, or are working to a specification, for a paragraph spacing rather than an indent, place \usepackage{parskip} in the preamble, omit the \paragraph in the text body, and simply enter the space in the text body. That will be preserved.

Comment: Yeah, I know that it depends. The question was really only regarding the typographic background behind the idea of *inline headings* (didn't even know this word combination before @David Carlisle's answer).